# Which abilities/summoner spells can be removed by using Cleanse or Quicksilver Sash?

Tags: league-of-legends

How can I tell whether an ability or summoner spell can be removed using Cleanse or Quicksilver Sash? Is there a list of such abilities?

Answer (score 3):

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanse

> Cleanse will remove any and all of the following effects: blind, charm, flee, slow, polymorph, silence, root (sometimes called Entangle, Snare or Immobilize), stun and taunt.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Quicksilver_Sash

> All forms of crowd control
>   Will remove almost all DoT damage from abilities, including but not limited to:  Blaze,  Noxious Blast,  Grog Soaked Blade,  Malefic Visions,  Poison Trail,  Toxic Shot, and  Deadly Venom.

Shows what Cleanse does and doesn't remove. QSS removes just about every debuff other than knockups.

Comment: Please include the relevant information from the links in this answer as well, in case the content of the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

QSS and Cleanse work in the same nature. They affect DEBUFFS. Most people think this means just CC. Such as a stun, or a snare. It will affect those and free you, but it also helps other things. It helps with blinds, it helps with DoTs (Damage over time spells). Such as bleeding effects, or malzahars dot will be cleansed. Importantly, it effects Mordekisers Ultimate. This both reduces the damage that he deals, and prevents him from getting a clone (Which is the best part of his skill)

It will cleanse ignite. It will cleanse exhusts slow, but it does not cleanse the damage reduction. That is important to know. You cannot cleanse during a taunt, which makes taunts extremely strong. You cannot cleanse while silenced either which makes that a strong counter. You can still use QSS though, because it is an item, not a spell.

Answer (score -1):

That link should answer your question, it looks like QSS cleanses everything. with the exception of knockups.

http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1708146

Comment: Badly wanted a list like some skills are close to be a CC , like you cant cleanse Nautilus Ulti , can you cleanse Blitz grab? Didnt know about Exhaust thanks tho